# GraphQL schema generator wont work on testing enviroment in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, graphql, nestjs

This is a piece of code of my test.spec.ts file:

```js
async beforeAll(): Promise<void> {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    this.app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    this.app.use(cookieParser());
    await this.app.init();
    this.httpServer = this.app.getHttpServer();

    const authService = this.app.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    const usersService = this.app.get<UsersService>(UsersService);

    const user = await usersService.findByUsername(testUser.username);
    const loginResult = await authService.login({
      password: user.password,
      username: user.username,
    });

    this.accessToken = loginResult.access_token;
  }
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "id". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.

```
  20 |     this.app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
  21 |     this.app.use(cookieParser());
> 22 |     await this.app.init();
     |     ^
  23 |     this.httpServer = this.app.getHttpServer();
  24 |
  25 |     const authService = this.app.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
```

This is the entity (typeORM):

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Entity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field(() => Int)
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;
}
```

I know for a fact that this is the entity that is causing the problem.

#### The important thing to notice here is that when running the application normally using: `npm run start:dev` it all works as expected, the mutations, queries, validations and authentications, etc.

#### But when trying to run the server under a testing enviroment it stops working when starting the application using `app.init()`

I cannot understand what is going on, why it works in a normal enviroment but stops when trying to run a test.

But also there is something funny about this, when commenting the app.init() line, it wont throw an error about GraphQL, it continues with the code successfully, it creates a dummy user and saves it, it even generates the JWT.

Further in the code, I run a mutation using supertest-graphql and graphql-tag:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import request from 'supertest-graphql';

beforeAll(async () => {
  const response = await request<{ createEntity: any }>(
    integrationTestManager.httpServer
  )
    .mutate(
      gql`
        mutation CreateEntity($createEntityInput: CreateEntityInput!) {
          createEntity(createEntityInput: $createEntityInput) {
            name
          }
        }
      `
    )
    .variables({
      createEntityInput: {
        name: testEntity.name,
      },
    })
    .expectNoErrors();

  console.log("response", response);
  createdEntity = response.data.createEntity;
});
```

But here, the response, under the body attribute it returns an error saying that it cannot POST to /graphql.

```
status: 404,
text: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
  '<html lang="en">\n' +
  '<head>\n' +
  '<meta charset="utf-8">\n' +
  '<title>Error</title>\n' +
  '</head>\n' +
  '<body>\n' +
  '<pre>Cannot POST /graphql</pre>\n' +
  '</body>\n' +
  '</html>\n',
method: 'POST',
path: '/graphql'
```

I truly cannot understand how to fix this, any advice is welcomed.